# Full-Text Search in Node JS with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, full-text-search

I'm trying to perform a full-text search on an array of strings in Mongoose and I am getting this error:

```
{ [MongoError: text index required for $text query]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'text index required for $text query',
  waitedMS: 0,
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'text index required for $text query',
  code: 27 }
```

However, I do have a text index declared on the field on the User Schema and I confirmed that the text index has been created because I am using mLab.
I am trying to perform a full-text search on fields

Here Is My User Schema:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        local: {
            firstName: String,
            lastName: String,
            username: String,
            password: String,
            fields: {type: [String], index: true}
        }
});
```

Here is My Code for the Full-Text Search:

```
User.find({$text: {$search: search}}, function (err, results) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(results);
                }
        });
```

Comment: Which mogoose version are you using?

Comment: Currently using Mongoose 4.7.0

Comment: you need to create a text index on your fields: [example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#examples)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For `$text` queries to work, MongoDB needs to index the field with a text index. To create this index by mongoose use

```
fields: {type: [String], text: true}
```

[See here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) for the MongoDB documentation of text indexes.

Answer (score 8):

You need to add a text index to your schema like below:

```
userSchema.index({fields: 'text'});
```

Or use `userSchema.index({'$**': 'text'});` if you want to include **all string fields**

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason adding a test index is not an option, you could also use the [regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator in your aggregation pipeline to match strings.

> $regex
>
> Provides regular expression capabilities for pattern matching strings
> in queries.
> MongoDB uses Perl compatible regular expressions (i.e.
> “PCRE” ) version 8.42 with UTF-8 support.
>
> To use $regex, use one of
> the following syntaxes:

```
{ <field>: { $regex: /pattern/, $options: '<options>' } }
{ <field>: { $regex: 'pattern', $options: '<options>' } }
{ <field>: { $regex: /pattern/<options> } }
```

> In MongoDB, you can also use regular expression objects (i.e.
> /pattern/) to specify regular expressions:

```
{ <field>: /pattern/<options> }
```